# Por qué no loguea, el hash pass si es igual en bbdd que el ingresado

Tags: php, mysqli, login, hash

La pregunta inicial consistía en que al intentar loguearme me devolvía la misma clave con diferentes hash por lo que era imposible hacer la comparación de password validado. Una vez que comenzaron a responderme reemplacé la descripcion del problema por el código de acá abajo.

```
   <?php
        session_start();
        ob_start();
        require('90_0encab.inc');
        require('92_0musr.inc');
    if(isset($_POST['bt-011']))
        {
            include('99_conn.php');
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $clave = $_POST['clave'];
            //$pass = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    // Ver el ejemplo de password_hash() para ver de dónde viene este hash.
    $hash = '98_clave';

    if (password_verify($clave, $hash)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
            $pass = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
            $error = '';
            $sql011 = "SELECT 98_idusr, 98_username, 98_clave, 98_grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username = '$username' AND 98_grupo = '$grupo'";
            $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
            $rows=$res011->num_rows;
            if ($rows > 0) {
                $row = $res011->fetch_assoc();
                $_SESSION['98_idusr'] = $row['98_idusr'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
                $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];
                $_SESSION['grupo'] = $row['grupo'];
                $error= "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
                    if ($grupo) 
                    {
                        switch ($grupo) 
                        {
                            case '1':   header('location: Index_dir.php');  break;
                            case '2':   header('location: Index_adm.php');  break;
                            case '3':   header('location: Index_ori.php');  break;
                            case '4':   header('location: Index_eva.php');  break;
                            case '5':   header('location: Index_con.php');  break;
                            case '6':   header('location: Index_root.php'); break;
                            default:    header('location: Index.html');     break;
                        }
                    }else{
            echo "La variable grupo no tiene datos";                
                    }
            }else{
                echo "No se encontraron registros.$username $pass $clave $grupo ";
        }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    //  } else {
    //  echo "usted se ha logueado correctamente como $username $pass $clave $grupo";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: hahaha.. ok.. tienes un problema.. que es password_hash?

Comment: el producto de hacedle hash a la clave que se ingresa por formulario

Comment: si me referia a si es una funcion interna o es tuya... pq si devuelve siempre algo distinto.. mmmm... algo esta mal ahi

Comment: use una rigurosa de php http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Comment: ahhh.. ya se cual es tu problema.. para validar un hash, se usa la funcion password_verify, o sea el usuario ingresa su pass, y tu pasas el hash de la db y el pass a esta funcion y te devuelve true o false ;)

Comment: ok entendí eso, en un ratito pongo el código para ver si es lógico, el tema es que no es lógico el reemplazo de la clave existente por una nueva así sea un par de dígitos y el nombre de usuario y otros dígitos aceptando como comparación el pass viejo que incluye lo que envia por formulario agregandole el hash, entonces eso tiene que estar mal! digo, no se!

Comment: Esta pregunta es sólo código. Intenta añadir algo de descripción: ¿qué es lo que hace? ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr? ¿Qué problemas/errores te encuentras? Tal y como está redactada ahora es de baja calidad, puedes leer [ask] para encontrar consejos para mejorar esta pregunta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, edité el copete de la pregunta.
Espero que le sirva a otros como me sirvió a mí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si la clave está encriptada con passsword hash no puedes traerla con la consulta que haces,pues las hash nuevas que se generan van a ser a nivel de string diferentes, por tanto debes traerla y verificarla en el texto con password_verify($clave, $hashdeladb);

Comment: todos se alían contra mí, ahora intento hacerlo, debe ser como dicen ustedes!

Comment: Edito el codigo arriba, pero a mi no me parece 'normalito' sólo estoy comparando el nombre y el grupo, de si la clave tiene o no hash (disculpen) me parece que nada de nada.

Comment: Así me deriva a donde yo quiero pero me parece que no verifica en absoluto la clave, no se, me parece!

Comment: Así no en realidad estás haciendo mal es así 

$sql = ""SELECT 98_idusr, 98_username, 98_clave, 98_grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username = '$username' AND 98_grupo = '$grupo'";

$res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
        $rows=$res011->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $row = $res011->fetch_assoc();
            if(password_verify($clave,$row['clave'])){//aquí es donde haces la verificación
echo 'clave correcta';
}else{echo 'clave incorrecta'; } /*agregas luego de acá el resto de tu código*/

Comment: En realidad debe ser así, no puedes verificar la clave si no tienes el hash antes, es decir no puedes saber si la clave está bien o mal hasta no traer la ya encriptada de la base de datos, por eso debes hacer primero la consulta solo teniendo en cuenta where el nombre de usuario y lo demás pero no la clave, algo asíObtengo con mi consulta  $nameuser= luis, $grupo=21, $id=1,$clave=!"3qa// osea clave encriptada//
$plana=maria123 // esta es la clave sin encriptar
ya teniendo eso sí puedo decir pasword_verify($cplana,$clave) que me devolverá true pues la encriptación y la clave plana son validas

Comment: ahora  entendí, dame unos minutitos gracias

Comment: Bien luis, muchas gracias!!!! era así nomás, ahora si estoy bien logueada me lleva a la pagina adecuada. tengo que renovar las claves de algunos de mis alter-egos para verificar que todo funcione, pero si no ponés todo bien  no anda ¡¡¡¡ espléndido!!!

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta rapida:

`password_hash` crea un hash para una cadena pasada, añadiendo en cada llamada su propia salt (una cadena aleatoria extra) y un tipo de algoritmo de encriptacion. Todo eso, lo agrega al hash.

Por lo tanto, cada vez que la llames vas a tener un hash distinto.

Para verificar si un pass es igual a un hash, se utiliza la función `password_verify`, la cual recibe un password (la cadena que ingreso el usuario) y un hash (lo que guardaste una sola vez en la base de datos).

Answer (score 1):

> la clave que fue encriptada en la base de datos con la function:

$claveregistro= password_hash($claveregistro, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

> debe ser traida para verificarla con

password_verify($clavelogin, $claveregistro);

Answer (score 1):

Veo que a tu código le falta todavía un poco de orden.

También, si es posible, usa consultas preparadas para evitar riesgos de Inyección SQL.

Aunque ya @LuisRomero ha respondido a lo esencial, sin ánimo de que marques esta respuesta como aceptada, considera escribir tu código más o menos así.

Lo comparto porque he trabajado la respuesta antes de que la respuesta de Luis fuese marcada como aceptada:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
require('90_0encab.inc');
require('92_0musr.inc');
if(isset($_POST['bt-011']))
{
    include('99_conn.php');
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $clave = $_POST['clave'];

    $hash = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    if (password_verify($clave, $hash)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';

//  $pass = password_hash($clave, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $grupo = $_POST['grupo'];
    $error = '';
    $sql011 = "SELECT 98_idusr, 98_username, 98_clave, 98_grupo FROM $t98 WHERE 98_username = '$username' AND 98_grupo = '$grupo'";
    $res011 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql011);
    $rows=$res011->num_rows;
    if ($rows > 0) {
        $row = $res011->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['98_idusr'] = $row['98_idusr'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['clave'] = $row['clave'];
        $_SESSION['grupo'] = $row['grupo'];
        $error= "El nombre de usuario o clave es incorrecto, Por favor vuelva a intentarlo";
        if ($grupo)
        {
            switch ($grupo)
            {
            case '1':   header('location: Index_dir.php');  break;
            case '2':   header('location: Index_adm.php');  break;
            case '3':   header('location: Index_ori.php');  break;
            case '4':   header('location: Index_eva.php');  break;
            case '5':   header('location: Index_con.php');  break;
            case '6':   header('location: Index_root.php'); break;
            default:    header('location: Index.html');     break;
            }

        }else{

            echo "La variable grupo no tiene datos";
        }

    }else{

        echo "No se encontraron registros.$username $pass $clave $grupo ";

    }


    } else {

        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }

}else{

    echo "No hay datos en el POST";
    //No sé de donde viene $conexion, así que cerramos aquí
    mysqli_close($conexion);

}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano como siempre, impecable lo tuyo. Funcionan ambas, las correcciones de Luis y tu codigo prolijito y acertado!
Soy muy nueva aqui y no se como funcionan el asunto de los puntos, y esos otros anexos, pero te agradezco.
Y creo que ahora no podés creer que ando 'de broma' por acá. Gracias!